# Setting application device compatibility iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm building an app for the iPhone and the app is only for iPod touch and iPhone. Where do I put this requirements? Because, when I tried to upload it to the apple store I can't find a place to indicate this and it assumes is also compatible with the iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Info.plist, you will want to add the UIDeviceFamily key and set it to 1.  Note that your application will still run on the iPad in compatibility mode, it just won't be a universal iPhone / iPad application.  I would highly recommend against doing anything to prevent the application from running on the iPad entirely.

A reference listing all possible keys you can add to your Info.plist to filter for functionality can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html).

Answer (score 1):

Set the "Targeted Device Family" in your Project or Target Build settings to iPhone.